# How to include image in html->pdf in php class

Tags: php, html, pdf

How can i include an image in an html->pdf class. Here is the code I'm currently working for:

```
<?php
session_start();

class PrintSomething
{
function requestPrintSomething()
{

    ob_start(); 
    $root = "../";
    $content = "";

    include $root."assets/library/html2pdf/html2pdf.class.php";

    $content .= "<img source = ../assets/images/Some_logo.PNG>";

    $content .= "<p>Something Date on " . $date . " at ".$time .":00 </p>";

    $content .= "
            <tr>
                <td> ".$somethinga ."</td>
                <td> ".$somethingb."</td>
            </tr>
    ";


    $content .= "
        </table>
    ";

    $html2pdf = new HTML2PDF('L');
    $html2pdf->WriteHTML($content);
    $html2pdf->Output('Something List '.date("Y-m-d").'.pdf');

    exit;}}?>
```

some info regarding the library:`/**
 * HTML2PDF Librairy - main class
 *
 * HTML => PDF convertor
 * distributed under the LGPL License
 *
 * @author  Laurent MINGUET <webmaster@html2pdf.fr>
 * @version 4.03
 */`

I hope someone know how to include image because I can't figure it out. I already tried the image source in html but somehow I've got a fatal error. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That img tag is not valid, src is the correct attribute to use.

```
$content .= "<img src='http://your_full_path/assets/images/Some_logo.PNG'>";
```

Also use your full path to the image.

Comment: I've got an error: Fatal error: Uncaught <span style="color: #AA0000; font-weight: bold;">ERREUR nÂ°6</span><br>Fichier :

Comment: Can you print $content before you put it in WriteHTML? Also your table starting tag is missing. Incorrect html can cause this error.

Comment: All works fine before, but the time that I include the image, error pops out

Comment: Did you try it with the correct syntax? Example 9 of this library shows: `<img src="http://demo.html2pdf.fr/examples/res/exemple09.png.php?px=5&amp;py=20" alt="image_php" >`

Comment: my syntax is here: $content .= "<img src='http://Something_Database/assets/images/something_logo.PNG'> ";

Comment: Can you try to test it with `<img src="http://demo.html2pdf.fr/examples/res/exemple09.png.php?px=5&amp;py=20" alt="image_php" >`? Just to make sure that the error is based in the library and not syntax or your image.

Comment: I downloaded the library and tested it with the examples. It all runs good here. (apache2 php54) The example really makes sure http:// is in the src. Can you paste the `$content`, I will test it here for you.

Comment: I am running it in localhost like this : $content .= "<img src='Something_Database/assets/images/something_logo.PNG'>; ";